# SQL - Percentage of one count by the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, percentage

I am trying to get the percentage of the first count by the second count. In other words, I want to do NbFirstCallResolutions / TotalCases * 100.

```
SELECT 

(SELECT 
COUNT([Incident].IncidentId)
FROM [Incident],[CaseResolution]
WHERE [Incident].IncidentId = [CaseResolution].RegardingObjectId
AND [CaseResolution].FirstCallResolution = 1
AND [Incident].CreatedOn >= @Parameter_StartDate 
AND [Incident].CreatedOn <= DATEADD(day,1,@Parameter_EndDate)
) AS NbFirstCallResolutions,

(SELECT 
COUNT([Incident].IncidentId) 
FROM [Incident]
WHERE [Incident].CreatedOn >= @Parameter_StartDate 
AND [Incident].CreatedOn <= DATEADD(day,1,@Parameter_EndDate)
) AS TotalCases

--SELECT NbFirstCallResolutions / TotalCases * 100.0
```

Not sure how to approach this one...

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  If so, you cannot use aliases in this way.  Just divide your two queries instead of worrying about the alias

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be able to be consolidated like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(coalesce([CaseResolution].FirstCallResolution, 0) / 
  COUNT([Incident].IncidentId) * 100
FROM 
  [Incident]
  left join [CaseResolution] on 
           [Incident].IncidentId = [CaseResolution].RegardingObjectId 
           AND [CaseResolution].FirstCallResolution = 1
WHERE 
  [Incident].CreatedOn >= @Parameter_StartDate 
  AND [Incident].CreatedOn <= DATEADD(day,1,@Parameter_EndDate
```

Notice that I summed the `1` value of `FirstCallResolution`, leaving the nulls as 0.  This would be equivalent of counting the rows.

Be sure to check your order of operations as I believe the multiply will occur first, followed by the divide.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please be sure to mark it as answered and upvote so others can know that it solved your problem.